# Hidden statusBar re-appears when I show an alert dialog, How to prevent it? (Android)

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar

I am using Android studio, and I have set up my main Activity in order to not show the statusBar. But when I display an alert dialog, the status bar reapears, and it won't hide after.
(Also if I receive a notfication on my phonem the status bar will also show up and not hide)

How can I fix that? Can I set my entire app to keep the status Bar hidden?

Here is my current setting: 
in onCreate()

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, did you try my solution below? I finally solved it and shared it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working solution!

In my onCreate method, I replaced the previous code by this one:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```